# How to send an email once a user completes a form in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I have built a blackberry application that allows a user to fill in information in some fields. Upon submit I want an email to be generated to me with that information filled. What is the best and simplest way of doing that?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How To - Create and send messages
Last Updated: 26 May 2009
Article Number: DB-00433
[link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800698/How_To_-_Create_and_send_messages.html?nodeid=1008283&vernum=0)

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate and create a Message object, then Transport.send()